# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I Received a crash report on my developers console which I have some trouble figuring out. The crash is reported by a Android 4.4 device and it is reported with the recent update I published for my app. I've seen other topics here on Stackoverflow on the same issue but as far as I know all of them are with users that are exceding the 64k method limit. I Used the apk analyse tool in Android Studio and it states that my dex file contains around 29000 methods and 37000 references. Now I'm not sure if I need to add those numbers or if I only need to look at the 29000 method count to determine if I exceed the 64k limit. I did test the apk on a 4.4 emulator and I can install and run it without issue.
Can someone shed some light on this?

```
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec2/[2]com.cubeactive.qnotelistfree-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec2/[2]com.cubeactive.qnotelistfree-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5003)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4589)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: implement muiltidex in your app

Comment: @quicklearner the apk analyze documentation states that the method count is a subset of the referenced method count. That would mean I'm well under the 64k limit. So why would enabling multidex help in this situation?

Comment: implement multidex in your app.I fixed the same issu with implementing multidex..try once

Comment: that happens, implement it

Comment: @NarenderReddy it's not possible for me to test it because I can not reproduce the error myself. Enabling multidex could resolve the issue but as far as I can see it would not help because I am under the method limit.

Comment: even too.try once